# Eliminating hangedup aynchronous task

Tags: c#

I've read quite a few things about asynchronous tasks and cancel tokens after specific amounts of times, ... .

What I'm not sure about is the following setup:
-I start an asynchronous task that hangs up
-After X seconds I want to eliminate said task (which by itself is unresponsive).

Is there any way to achieve this goal, aside from killing the main program and restarting it?

Comment: Nope. It's buggy code and the way to solve this problem is to fix the bug. In newer vesrions even `Thread.Abort` no longer works (not that it's applicable to this case but still).

Comment: @Evk I feared just that, still though there are situations where its not code but microsoft based (file functions work with the base OS file functions and those have no integrated timeout as best example.....when I write and read huge masses of files I regularly run into exactly that problem that it hangs up without knowing it as there is no timeout)